# Row details in DataGrid - can I bind them to an 'inner' collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, expression-blend, wpfdatagrid

I have two data structures that look like this -

```
class Car
{
    string CarModel;
    string CarColor;
    string CarAge;
}

class Person
{
    int ID;
    string FirstName;
    string Surname;
    ObservableCollection<Car> Cars;
}

public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }
```

So I have a collection of type Car within a collection of type Person. I want to display this in a DataGrid that looks like this where each Person can have zero or more cars -

[image]

The following xaml code takes care of the rows but it doesn't handle the row details -

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Firstname" Binding="{Binding Firstname}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding Surname}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Anyone know if it is possible to display a DataGrid with row details bound to an inner collection, (in this case `ObservableCollection<Car> Cars`)?

Comment: Does it have to be a `DataGrid`? My first instinct upon seeing your sample is to want to use an `ItemsControl`. DataGrid provides more advanced features such as built-in editing, selection, and sorting capabilities, however if you want to simply display a collection of items, an ItemsControl is easier to style in the format you specified

Comment: I don't need editing but I do need selecting and sorting features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put something like an `ItemsControl` in the RowDetailsTemplate

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Firstname" Binding="{Binding Firstname}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding Surname}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CarTemplate}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```